# Need a RPA solution to go through a PDF to know to detect whether all required pages are signed

Tags: pdf, automation, signature

We need a RPA solution that would go through all pages of a PDF file and confirm whether all pages that require signature are signed or not.

Few points to keep in mind:

1. The RPA solution could be a UIPath or Power Automate based solution.
2. The pages that contains certain text are the clues where the bot should look for the signature.
3. The signatures could a digital/electronic one done via Adobe Sign
4. In some cases this PDF could be printed, signed with pen and scanned back as PDF.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.